# PHP conversion against injection for numerical parameters

Tags: php, mysql, sql, security

I know that the ultimate way is to use `mysqli_real_escape_string` function. But it is pretty long and for numerical values I often use `$value + 0` statement. Is it secure enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. Don't forget to use "real" which is the new version of mysqli_escape_string ;)

Btw, you should use prepared statement with mysqli:

You can read more about this on: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

This will avoid using mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: Thank you for the article - there are so many characters :))) But the initil question was regarding is that way safe enough.

Comment: Yes I just edited my post according to the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

for numerical variable mysqli_real_escape_string maybe cant help you

for example in blind sql inejction

i think you can use intval() function for more safety

this link more explain about this function

https://www.php.net/intval

be successfull

Comment: At least the query will generate error but the injection will be impossible as I can understand